# Visual C++: cast to function type is illegal, g++ also yields an error

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++-2019, g++10

My generated code always used unnecessary many parenthesis simply to make certain, that the C++ code was actually doing what the AST expressed. This is first time I'm getting this compiler error, which I cannot explain -- also before I've used custom types.

(define G_ERROR to get an error...)
Visual C++ 2019 yields the following error:

cl -c tmp0.cpp -I ..\Documents\WORK\boost_1_77_0 -DG_ERROR

```
tmp0.cpp(32): error C2066: cast to function type is illegal
tmp0.cpp(40): error C2675: unary '+': 'abstractValue<32>' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
tmp0.cpp(40): error C2088: '+': illegal for class
```

g++ v10 yields the following error:

g++-10 -std=c++11 -c tmp0.cpp -I /mnt/c/Users/userName/Documents/WORK/boost_1_77_0/ -DG_ERROR

```
tmp0.cpp:40:3: error: no match for ‘operator+’ (operand type is ‘abstractValue<>’)
```

```
#include <vector>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>

#include <type_traits>
#include <functional>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <set>


struct undetermined
{
};
template<std::size_t SIZE=32>
class abstractValue
{   public:
    abstractValue(const double);
    abstractValue(const undetermined&);

    abstractValue operator+(const abstractValue&) const;
};
struct instance
{
double DTEMP;
abstractValue<> function_231(
        std::vector<boost::optional<abstractValue<>> >&_r
    ) const{
        auto &r = _r.at(231);
        if (
            !r
        )r = 
#ifdef G_ERROR
(
#endif
            abstractValue<>(
                undetermined()
            )
#ifdef G_ERROR
        )
#endif
        +(
            abstractValue<>(
                DTEMP
            )
        );
        return r.value();
        
    }
};
```

Comment: `abstractValue<>( undetermined() )` -> `abstractValue<>{  undetermined() }`

Comment: Most vexing parse. `abstractValue<>(undetermined())` can be interpreted as a function type, a function that returns `abstractValue<>` and takes as a parameter a function taking no parameters and returning `untedermined`. Then you have `(SomeType)+(abstractValue<>(DTEMP))` - this is taken as "construct `abstractValue<>(DTEMP)`, apply unary plus operator to it, then cast to `SomeType`".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
abstractValue<>(undetermined())
```

Because both `abstractValue<>` and `undetermined` are types, there are two interpretations of this without further context:

1. It is a functional-style explicit cast expression creating a prvalue of type `abstractValue<>` with `(undetermined())` its initializer.
2. It is a type-id, namely the type of a function returning `abstract<>` with a single parameter of type "*function without parameters returning `undetermined`*" (which is adjusted to "*pointer to function without parameters returning `undetermined`*").

You want it to mean the first, not the second. When writing

```
abstractValue<>(undetermined()) + /*...*/
```

it cannot have the meaning of 2. and `+` can only be the binary `+` operator, but because there are C-style explicit cast expressions in the form of `(T)E` where `T` is a type and `E` an expression, in

```
(abstractValue<>(undetermined())) + /*...*/
```

the whole expression could also be such a C-style explicit cast expression with `abstractValue<>(undetermined())` being `T` and `+/*...*/` being `E` with `+` the *unary* `+`.

Because the grammar is ambiguous here, there is a rule saying that any construct that could be interpreted as a type-id in such a situation, is interpreted as a type-id. Therefore the interpretation as 2. is chosen here.

You can avoid this by either simply not using the extra parentheses (as seen they can *not* always be added without affecting the meaning of an expression) or you can use brace-initialization instead of initialization with parentheses, because braces cannot appear in a function type, disqualifying the 2. immediately in all contexts:

```
abstractValue<>{undetermined()}
```

or

```
abstractValue<>(undetermined{})
```

or

```
abstractValue<>{undetermined{}}
```